# Search Articles Button Not Interactable

Tags: java, selenide

I need to automation testing of a website https://www.buletintv3.my/. There is a search articles function. I'm facing after clicing the search svg, there is no search box pop up/display.

Here is the code:

```
@Test
    public void testSearchArticles() {
        extentTest = extentManager.getExtentReports().createTest("Search Articles Test");

        $x("//*[@id=\"__next\"]/div[3]/section[1]/div/nav/div[1]/button").click();
        $x("//input[@class='form-control me-sm-2']").click();
        $x("//input[@class='form-control me-sm-2']").setValue("bola");
        $x("//input[@class='form-control me-sm-2']").pressEnter();
    }
```

Error:

> Element should be interactable {By.xpath: //input[@class='form-control
> me-sm-2']} Element: '' Actual value: hidden, opacity=1

Please let me know what wrong with the code or approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 scenarios why are you getting this.

`Element should be interactable` exception is thrown, when element actually exists in DOM, but can't be reached (invisible or overlapped by another element).

In your case:

1. After site load subscribe modal is appearing for me, so it can overlap.
2. You don't wait for input visibility (so setting value failed, because input is not appeared).

```java
Selenide.open("https://www.buletintv3.my/");
// in case if you have modal, you should close it
$("#ins-lead-collection-on-overlay [id*=close]").shouldBe(exist).click();
$("#ins-lead-collection-on-overlay [id*=close]").shouldNotBe(visible);

SelenideElement searchButton = $("[id*=next] #navbarNavDropdown button");
Selenide.executeJavaScript("arguments[0].click()", searchButton);
SelenideElement searchInput = $("#floating-search-bar input").shouldBe(visible);
searchInput.sendKeys("MB");
searchInput.pressEnter();
searchInput.shouldNotBe(visible);
```